# How to add GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY in MySQL table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a DB2 Table and i am trying to convert into  MySQL table . This is the DB2 table :

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NO MAXVALUE NO CYCLE CACHE 100),
  ACTIVE SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)#
```

i have converted to MySQL like :

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  ID BIGINT ,
  ACTIVE SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

and i am running one procedure

```
create procedure test_proced(
    in to_create bigint,
    out created bigint
)
begin
     set created = (select count(vnr.id) from MY_TABLE vnr);
    while (created < to_create) do
      insert into MY_TABLE (active) values(0);
      set created = created + 1;
    end while;
end;
```

But after adding with above procedure on this table , I am getting some error like :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

Now i am suspecting the `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` . Is this error due to this problem ?  If it is , How to convert to corresponding MySQL Table ?

Comment: I believe it's just as simple as adding auto_increment as column option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySQL you can use [**`AUTO_INCREMENT`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html):

```sql
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ACTIVE SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

A new value is going to be automatically generated for column `ID` every time a new row is inserted in `MY_TABLE`. Each auto-generated value is by default equal to the value of the immediately preceding (in order of insertion) record plus 1.

**Note:** The default is to start at `1` with a `1` step value.

Comment: Fast and clear, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adding AUTO INCREMENT to your primary key would fix this issue.